# Using proxies with Unirest python

Tags: python, proxy, unirest

hey i Know this question has been asked before but there is no clear answer anywhere.

Problem : I am using 'Unirest' in python. The code is working fine for me

```
import unirest
data = unirest.get(url.strip(), headers = headers)
print data.raw_body
```

But I have to do a large number of hits so I need proxy switching mechanism. But not able to find how to add proxy in 'unirest'.

Please help

Comment: Why don't you use `requests`?

Comment: I tried, but this particular website is not giving response if I use requests.
url -> "https://m.directtextbook.com/ourbuybacktable.php?ean=9780030225222".

if you have idea of any other library, it would be great help.

Comment: The site doesn't 'like' `requests`'s default User-Agent, you must chenge it in `headers` - eg `r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'my-ua'})`

Comment: user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)'}
This is working with Unirest. but not with requests.

Comment: Sorry, it works on my machine when I change the User-Agent. Using the url you provided I get the contents of the page in `r.text`.

Comment: Can you please share the User_agent that you used

Comment: Here is the full code I used: `import requests; url = 'https://m.directtextbook.com/ourbuybacktable.php?ean=9780030225222'; r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'my-ua'}); print(r.text)` and I think I got the full page. Without the User-Agent it just says "We cannot find any prices for this book."